# angular-meteor: notify client when new document inserted

Tags: angularjs, meteor

I am implementing a notification system using angularjs and meteor.

In my publication code,

I have something like this:

```
    var retVal = Notifications.find({recipient: userId});

var handle = retVal.observeChanges({
    //when a new notification is added
    added: function (doc, idx) {
        count++;
        if (!initializing){
            console.log("A record was added");
            self.changed("counts", userId, {count: count});
        }
    },

    removed: function (doc, idx) {
        count--;
        self.changed("counts", userId, {count: count});    
    }

});
```

and in the end I return retVal.
In my controller, I subscribe to that publication.
The code seems fine and the server triggers the added function whenever a new document is added. But how do I notify the client (something like trigger a function in my controller) when a new document is added? The added function only triggers in the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see your publication header, do you expect parameters there?

For binding a collection all you need to do is use the $meteorCollection service like that:

```
$scope.notifications = $meteorCollection(Notifications);
```

We just updated our API (version 0.6.0-alpha) and it does observeChanges internally to look for any change in the collection.

But don't forget to subscribe to that collection - you can do that in 2 ways:

1. `$meteorSubscribe.subscribe("publicationName", parameters)` - which returns a promise.
2. `$scope.notifications = $meteorCollection(Notification).subscribe("publicationName", parameters);`  - which is shorter but doesn't return a promise.

If one of the parameters changes the publication, you should surround it with autorun like that:

```
$meteorUtils.autorun($scope, function(){
  $meteorSubscribe.subscribe("publicationName", {
        limit: parseInt($scope.getReactively('perPage')),
        skip: (parseInt($scope.getReactively('page')) - 1) * parseInt($scope.getReactively('perPage')),
        sort: $scope.getReactively('sort')
      }));
});
```

- $scope.getReactively is a new method we added that makes a regular $scope variable to a reactive one. this means that when it changes, that autorun will re-run.

Hope it helps, let me know how can I improve the answer and the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should replicate your `observeChanges()` on the client.
So, it will be able to observe the client side collection that is created and synchronized by the `subscribe()` function.

Comment: How do I do that with angularjs? I use the services $collection and $methods. I searched for observeChanges method but I cannot find a method like that.